# Is this a correct translation of this poem into Quenya?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, tolkien-languages

I'm starting to learn  a bit of Quenya and I'm trying to transate a small poem I wrote last year to the language. I still have small understanding about all the suffixes.

The original poem is in Portuguese:

> Deito sob o luar
>   Afago o chão de orvalho
>   Sonho com seu abraço

In English is something like (also presenting some variations I'm using because there is some Quenya word I didn't find directly):

> I lie under the moonlight
>   I caress [or 'touch'] a ground of dew
>   I dream about your hugs [or 'your arms'].

And my last attempt was:

> Caitan nu i-isilmë
>   Ápan talan rosséva
>   Ólan ranculyat

Is this correct?

---

EDIT: @Bobby Newmark provided some improvements:

> Caitan nu i isilmë
>   Appan talan rosséva
>   Ólan ranculyat

Also, he asked for a tengwar transcription of it. Hope it's right:

[image: Tengwar version of the poem]

Comment: I might be able to help.  I'll take a look at it tonight when I have all my Quenya stuff.

Comment: Thank you in advance for any help, @BobbyNewmark!

Comment: Oh wow...that's beautiful, @CalWal!  I love the way Tengwar looks!

Comment: So do I! And the idea of it being a phonetic writing system is something I really like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look.

First the references (and if you're interested in Quenya, this is a great site), I get everything from [Ardalambion](http:///http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/) and [this](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/Quettaparma.pdf) dictionary.

Your first word "Caitan" seems correct. "Caita-" is the aorist form of "lie" and the "-n" is the pronominal suffix for "I".

Here's the definition of "Caita-":

> **caita-** vb. "lie" (= lie down, not "tell something untrue"), aorist
>   tense "lies" in the sentences *sindanóriello caita mornië* "out of a
>   grey land darkness lies" (Nam, RGEO:67)

And here is the construction:

> We also see -i- before all pronominal endings; indeed
>   Tolkien very often cites Quenya primary verbs as aorist forms with the
>   ending -n "I" attached (e.g. carin "I make", LR:362, tulin "I come",
>   LR:395). A-stem verbs show no variation, but end in -a whether or not
>   any further ending follows (e.g. lanta "falls", lantar "fall" with a
>   plural subject, **lantan "I fall"**, etc.)

Next word "nu" is also correct.

> **nu** prep. "under" (LR:56, Markirya, Nam, RGEO: 66, MC:214; the
>   Etymologies alone gives no [q.v.] instead). In Mar-nu-Falmar,
>   nuhuinenna, q.v. Prefix nú- in nútil, q.v

So then we have "i" which is Quenya for "the".  I don't think you need the hyphen here. The hyphen is usually used when a compound word is created, and that is not the case. (For example *Mar-nu-Falmar*, "Land (lit. Home) under Waves" is a compound word, a name for Númenor after it sinks)

"isilmë" is moonlight, so that's correct!

> **isilmë** (þ) noun "moonlight", occurring in Markirya; free translation
>   "the moon" in MC:215 (isilmë ilcalassë, literally "moonlight
>   gleaming-in" = "in the moon gleaming"). Isilmë also appears as the
>   name of a Númenorean woman (UT:210).

So far so good! Let's look at the next line.

"Ápan" is not quite right.  It should be Appan "I touch" with Appa- being the aorist form and the "-n" the pronominal suffix. (I don't see any reference with the accent over the a.)

> **appa-** vb. "touch" (in the literal sense; contrast #ap-, q.v.) (VT44:26)

"Talan" is ground.

> **talan** (talam-, e.g. pl. talami) noun "floor, base, ground" (TALAM)

This next one is a little tricky, but I think you got it. "rosséva" is "of dew", with "rossé" being "dew" and the suffix "-va" meaning "of". I am not sure of the accent. It looks right, but I couldn't find the specific rule.

Here's the definition:

> **rossë** noun "fine rain, dew" (ROS1, PM:371)

And the construction:

> Then there is the possessive, by some called the "associative" or
>   "adjectival case"; Tolkien himself speaks of it as a
>   "possessive-adjectival...genitive" in WJ:369. This case has the ending
>   -va (-wa on nouns ending in a consonant). Its general function is like the English genitive, to express ownership: Mindon Eldaliéva "Tower of
>   the Eldalië". The function of the possessive was long poorly
>   understood. In Namárië it occurs in the phrase yuldar...miruvóreva,
>   "draughts...of mead".

And finally, line three.

"Ólan" is also correct.  "Óla-" is the verb dream and again "-n" is the pronominal suffix.

> **óla-** vb. "to dream" (said to be "impersonal", probably meaning that
>   the dreamer is mentioned in the dative rather than the nominative)
>   (UT:396)

The last word is very difficult, and I think you nailed it. "ranculyat" breaks down like so: "rancu-lya-t", rancu-=arm, lya=your and t=dual plural.  Quenya has a special plural for natural pairs, like arms or eyes, and you got that suffix correct. Also, the "a" in "lya" does not get a stress because the dual plural suffix is "-t". (The first "u" may need to be stressed, but I couldn't find a reference for it.)

So...here's the definition:

> **ranco** ("k") noun "arm", stem *rancu- given the primitive form ¤ranku,
>   hence also pl. ranqui ("q") (RAK)

and the construction:

> 2nd person sg. formal/polite: -lya "your, thy"

The plural suffix of a pair:

> Like the nominative plural, the nominative dual is formed with one of
>   two endings. Most nouns take the ending -t, as in the word máryat "her
>   hands" (two hands, a pair of hands) in Namárië. "Two ships, a couple
>   of ships" is likewise ciryat (cirya "ship")

And finally, the stress:

> When stressed, most of these pronouns have long vowels: ní, lyé, tyé,
>   sé, sá etc. The vowel however remains short in the dual forms in -t
>   (VT49:51).

So, the "a" in "-lya" stays short!

My translation would be very similar to yours:

Caitan nu i isilmë
Appan talan rosséva
Ólan ranculyat

You have done amazingly well, as far as I'm concerned. I think you'd like this [course](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/qcourse.htm) from Ardalambion...it's where I learned everything I know.

Also, it would be great to see it in Tengwar!

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you, Bobby! I will write in tengwar and post it here so we can take a look on it! 
I'm studying using this very same course! It's amazing!

Comment: I made a hand-written attempt to provide a tengwar transcription. I'll try to find a good tengwar font to provide a better image ASAP. ;-)

Comment: Awesome,CaWal!  I'll take a look at it sometime today.  Isn't that course amazing?

Comment: Edited there! Added a better image and corrected an error in my handwriting (I wrote "raculyat" before). 

It's amazing indeed! It's really concise and well structured!

Comment: Three things: 1. You contradict yourself (or rather, your source) a bit here. _Ólan_ is the verb _óla-_ with the subject/object pronoun suffix, so if the dictionary is correct that it is an impersonal verb with the dreamer in the dative, _ólan_ is **not** right. It should be _óla nin_ or _nin óla_ ‘for me is dreamed/[it] dreams’. 2. In a language that has a [T–V distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T–V_distinction), the informal version seems more appropriate in a poem about dreaming of someone's embraces (unless they're a stranger).

Comment: 3. I would also claim (though nothing seems to confirm it explicitly) that the nominative-accusative is an odd case for the thing you're dreaming about. An instrumental would seem more likely to me; thus, with all three things together, I would suggest ***nin óla rancutyanten*** for that line.

Comment: Good point. In Faskanger's Quentaparma Quenyanna  its provided that 'DREAM (verb) óla- (said to be
"impersonal", probably meaning that the dreamer is mentioned in the dative rather than the nominative: *Óla i Eldan, "the Elf dreams") – UT:396'.  I have also found about "-nten" as the dual+instrumental and "tyë" as the intimate or familiar "thou", that you are providing in the possessive. So your proposal seems very solid for me. Let me ask you something to learn more about it: if it was something polite, like a lament for a non-familiar maiden, would be better  "Óla nin ranculyanten"?